# How to change tab view with pagination in MVC Core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a tab view to show 2 different records and added pagination to them. Everything works fine but when I click on the second tabview's pagination , it opens the first tabview automatically. When I switch to the other tab view , then I see the second page. I only want to show the tabview first when I click their pagination. How can I do this ?

My Controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> List(int? page,int? pagePast)
        {

           
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var pageNumberPast = pagePast ?? 1;
            XCardViewModel viewModel = await _mediator.Send(new GetXQuery());
            ViewBag.presentPageCount = viewModel.X;
            XCardViewModel pastViewModel = await _mediator.Send(new GetPastXQuery());
            ViewBag.pastPageCount = pastViewModel.PastX;
            if(pageNumber != 1 || pageNumber == 1)
            {
            ViewBag.PageList = viewModel.X.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5);

            }

            if(pageNumberPast !=1 || pageNumberPast == 1)
            {

           ViewBag.PastPageList = pastViewModel.PastX.ToPagedList(pageNumberPast, 5);
              
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Record.cshtml

```
<div class="tabbarClass">
    <a class="card" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openTab(event, 'presentRecord');">
        <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding w3-border-blue">
            <h2>Current Records</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="card" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openTab(event, 'pastRecord');">
        <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">
            <h2>Past Records</h2>
        </div>    
    </a>  
<div>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PageList)
                {
                       
                        @item.Header

                       
                }
            </div>

      

        <div id="paginationOrder">
          
                
            @Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.PageList, page => Url.Action("Record", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions {   })
                
        </div>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.PastPageList)
                {
                       
                        @item.Header

                       
                }
            </div>

      

        <div id="pastpaginationOrder">
          
                
            @Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.PastPageList, page => Url.Action("Record", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions {   })
                
        </div>

  <script>

        var presentPage = '@ViewBag.presentPageCount.Count';
        const pageModal = document.querySelector("#paginationOrder");     
        if(presentPage<5 || presentPage==5){
            pageModal.style.display = "none";
        }

        var pastPage = '@ViewBag.pastPageCount.Count';
      
        const pastpageModal = document.querySelector("#pastpaginationOrder");
        if (pastPage < 5 || pastPage == 5) {
            pastpageModal.style.display = "none";
        }
        
        function openTab(evt, tableID) {
            
            var i, x, tablinks;
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-blue", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tableID).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-blue";
     }

    </script>
```